# gitlab-ci.yml: create parallel stage for each cmake presets

Tags: cmake, gitlab-ci

My project use `cmake` to compile and have the following presets:

```bash
cmake --list-presets                    
Available configure presets:

  "ROBOT_1"
  "ROBOT_2"
  "ROBOT_3"
  "ROBOT_4"
```

I want to compile each preset in parallel in my `gitlab-ci.yml`.

I try to do like this but I'm looking for a better way were the `ROBOTS` variable will directly feed by the `cmake --list-presets` command:

```yaml
variables:
  ROBOTS:
    - ROBOT_1
    - ROBOT_2
    - ROBOT_3
    - ROBOT_4

build:
  stage: build
  image: $BUILD_IMAGE
  script:
    - |
      for i in $(seq 0 $((${#ROBOTS[@]} - 1))); do
        ROBOT=${ROBOTS[$i]}
        echo "Building for robot $ROBOT"
        cmake --preset=$ROBOT
        cmake --build build/$ROBOT
      done
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/$ROBOT/$ROBOT.tar
```

Comment: I don't know of a great way to generate and build multiple CMake presets with just CMake, and actually, I think that might work out the way you hope it will in terms of system resource usage. A process can easily control how many threads it uses, but I don't know if it can ask the OS about how the machine's cores are being used by all processes to collaboratively coordinate multi-processor usage with other processes. Related: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/JOB_POOLS.html and https://discourse.cmake.org/t/efficiency-issues-with-externalproject-sub-builds-under-ninja/3241/10

Comment: See also the [`--parallel`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-j) argument to the CMake build command. If you give each build command a fraction of the CPU cores, then if some builds take less work than others, you'll end up with less utilization of the cores. If you tell each build command to use more than a "fair portion" of the cores, then some threads will spend some time waiting on others. (at least- as far as I understand. maybe I understand wrongly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`parallel:matrix:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) to create a matrix of jobs that will run in parallel.

For example, this would create 4 parallel jobs, one for each variation of the environment variable `ROBOT`.

```py
build:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ROBOT: ["ROBOT_1", "ROBOT_2", "ROBOT_3", "ROBOT_4"]
  script:
    - echo $ROBOT
  # ...
```